# Japanese phrase for "Eyes wide open in surprise"

Tags: translation, verbs, phrases, english-to-japanese

So I'm a bit confused because I'm still learning Japanese, and I have learned there are shortened words or small phrases that take a lot more to say in English, so I was wondering if there is an actual saying in Japanese for when someone's eyes are wide open in surprise. I used google translate, which I don't fully trust so it's not an official reference, but I got a very literal answer so I'm wondering if that would be preferred.

Google Translate:

```
English: I open my eyes wide in surprise
Japanese: 私{わたし}は驚{おどろ}いて私{わたし}の目{め}を広{ひろ}く開{ひら}きます
```

I don't trust this answer of course, so I usually use the Japanese Dictionary, Jisho.org, as a more trustworthy source, and it shows a phrase that seems to be what I'm looking for:

```
目{め}を見{み}張{は}る/me o miharu
```

(Link: [https://jisho.org/word/目を見張る](https://jisho.org/word/%E7%9B%AE%E3%82%92%E8%A6%8B%E5%BC%B5%E3%82%8B))

So would it be right to try and say the sentence (sounds like a fragment in English, but it's for a song), "I open my eyes wide in surprise" like this:

```
私{わたし}は目{め}を見{み}張{は}っている
```

PS: Also, the phrase, "I open my eyes wide in surprise", is meant to mean something more like the person is doing the action, thus, the te-form of the phrase in Japanese. Sorry for the long question, and hope it wasn't too crazy, thanks!

Comment: note that jisho.org uses [EDICT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EDICT), which is a free dictionary compiled by volunteers. In most cases it's okay but I'd not rely on it 100%. If you want a really "trustworthy source", I'd recommend a commercial dictionary, maybe even a monolingual one. See [this post](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/a/761/3295) for some recommendations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to say this, and I can't guarantee I'll be of much help without knowing the full context of the song, but I can try my best. I'll assume there's a line that follows it, and add the romaji assuming someone who's not a native speaker will be singing this (?) and would like to hear how it sounds:

[驚いて]目を丸くして
[odoroite] me wo maruku shite

lit. "My eyes go round with surprise"

[驚きに]目を見開いて
[odoroki ni] me wo mihiraite
lit. "My eyes widened with surprise" (a bit more fancy)

[びっくりして]目を見開いて
[bikkuri shite] me wo mihiraite
lit. "Startled, my eyes widened" (this sounds the best to me personally in Japanese)

It is possibly less direct, though not necessarily better (i.e. more 'Japanese') to omit the 'surprised' in the lines I provided, so feel free to remove the words in the brackets if that's your thing.

The example you provided (私は目を見張っている) is definitely fine too, though it's not something I personally see used a ton in casual conversation; in a song it's perfectly fine, with the exception of dropping the は or even the entire 私は, and changing the いる to て, depending on context.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The line that comes after would be, "I found a book in my bag not owned by me" but I haven't translated it yet to Japanese, although I believe the answer you gave was great anyway. Thanks!

Comment: Also, this is a bit off-topic, but is it possible you could explain in more clarity how を would be used in a sentence and what for? I have tried to search for some answers to this, but I still don't understand the explanation, and I suspect it's because there really isn't an English equivalent.

Comment: を would be used to denote, generally, the subject of a sentence -
 something that has an action being performed to it. In this case, the subject would be 目, or the eyes. The distinctions made between the other particles, the most common of which are は and が, are nebulous and a bit difficult to explain concisely, but generally を indicates the subject of a sentence.

Example: "Pet a cat." 
猫[を]撫でる
In this sentence, the cat is the object with an action being performed to it (pet).

Feel free to ask more - I can explain to the best of my ability.

Comment: I think I'm starting to get it, thanks. So, for example, would this make sense?

Comment: 野球を充てる((I) hit the baseball)

Comment: Not quite. 野球 refers to the sport of baseball itself, not the physical ball. That would be like saying that you threw the lacrosse. A better translation would be ボールを打つ (I don't believe the distinction is made between a regular ball vs specifically a baseball very often).

Comment: 充てる is also a bit off. It's usually used when talking about appropriating funds or resources of some kind.　当てる would be more fitting, but while technically correct, 打つ is far more used. That said, your usage of the を particle was correct.

Comment: Wow, well that cleared up a lot, thanks for all your help. With more examples and practice, I'm pretty sure I'll get the hang of ”を”, and thanks for letting me know about the other mistakes I made. You were a big help!:)

Comment: No problem. Good luck with your studies and the song!

Answer (score 1):

I've seen theses expressions in manga/light novels, so not sure if they are used much in real life:

- [目を見開く](https://kotobank.jp/jeword/%E8%A6%8B%E9%96%8B%E3%81%8F)
- [目を白黒する](https://kotobank.jp/jeword/%E7%99%BD%E9%BB%92) (though this one seems to be somewhat different in meaning)